# FQL query limit

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I was trying this simple query on the Graph Explorer

```
SELECT eid FROM event_member 
           WHERE (uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) 
                  OR uid = me())
```

and it returns "error: Request Failed."

Then, I started reading here and some forums and it had to do with the limits, so I've tried limiting by 20 my friend list and it worked.

Which is the limit? and where (the query, or the results given)? There's nothing in the documentation as far as I know.

**EDIT:**

What if I order my whole friends by `mutual_friend_count` and then limit by 200? I also added `start_time>now()`. It's not the best way to find the closest friends, but it doesn't need permissions to access your stream (to check likes and comments from friends).

```
SELECT eid FROM event_member 
WHERE (uid = me() 
OR uid IN (SELECT uid FROM user 
           WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()
                         ORDER BY mutual_friend_count DESC) 
           LIMIT 200)
       )
AND start_time > now()
```

1. Is it too many queries inside another one? They are three actually.
2. It isn't efficent
   in some cases. For example, in my case, the top mutual friends lives
   in my hometown, and I'm interested in events from my actual city.

Imagine I limit the events retrieved by only 5 per user. It shouldn't be so hard ONLY IF the user had a list of upcoming events he/she is attending/unsure.

For example, doing `graph.facebook.com/user-id/events` "seems" to work like that.

However, I guess reading from event_member table it's not so easy because it would traversing a large database of events and checking one by one if any friend of mine is in there. Am I wrong?

Comment: It's not a simple query, it's actually a huge query. Can you imagine how long did it take 'SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())' if you have 5000 friends? And you have to call 'eid FROM event_member' from each of this 5000 friends. So it's normal when you get timeout error, i.e.  "error: Request Failed."

Comment: You're right. I edited my question. Please, take a look at it if you can :)

Answer (score 0):

The limits are as far as I know (and you wrote it as well) not documented. I'd recommend that you use the

```
 LIMIT start, end
```

in your subquery as follows

```
SELECT eid FROM event_member 
           WHERE (uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me() LIMIT 0,24) 
                  OR uid = me())
```

A best practice that I use is to get the number or friends in advance, and then create "breakdown queries", i.e. you've got 187 friends and the desired limit is 25 per query, then you'll need to 8 "breakdown queries" to get the whole event list from your friends. This can also be done via a batch request (but friends need to be counted first in a separate query).

The general limit of these calls on Facebook's side are either the processing time or the length of the result I guess...

Comment: Ok, I undertand your point. I've edited my question. It's not so easy for me I think. Do you mean multi-query when you says batch request?